# asp:DropDownList DataBind HTML Output

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, drop-down-menu, minify

Is there a way of getting the `asp:DropDownList` bound items to display the output inline rather than with linebreaks, I currently have around 1000+ items bound to a `DropDownList` multiple times which is causing so many lines in the `HTML` & causing the page to load slowly

What currently displays (Short Version)

```
<select name="randomName" onchange="randomOnChane" id="randomId">
        <option value="42">Test</option>
        <option value="43">Test</option>
        <option value="44">Test</option>
        <option value="45">Test</option>
        <option value="46">Test</option>
        <option value="47">Test</option>
        <option value="48">Test</option>
        <option value="49">Test</option>
        <option value="50">Test</option>
        <option value="51">Test</option>
    </select>
```

What I'd like

```
<select name="randomName" onchange="randomOnChane" id="randomId">
    <option value="42">Test</option><option value="43">Test</option><option value="44">Test</option>
    <option value="45">Test</option><option value="46">Test</option><option value="47">Test</option>
    <option value="48">Test</option><option value="49">Test</option><option value="50">Test</option>
    <option value="51">Test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the control then intercept the rendered HTML and filter it, like so

```
class MyLinelessWebControl: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList()
{    
    protected override RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter tempWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        base.RenderControl(tempWriter);

        writer.Write(sw.ToString().Replace("\r\n",""));
    }
}
```

That being said, I doubt the removal of newline characters will improve performance much.

Comment: Nice bit of code, but i also doubt it will improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

1000+ items in a dropdown list? No wonder your page is loading slowly. Minifying your HTML won't make much difference performance wise. You should look at a "auto complete" functionality, such as http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/.

Also as a user i won't be happy to scroll through a list with more then 1000+ items :)